# Why does $u$-substitution result in an incorrect solution to some integrals?

Tags: calculus, integration, definite-integrals

I understand that the integral $\int_0^\pi x\sin(x)\cos(x) dx$ can be found by applying a trigonometric identity and integrating by parts. My questions is why does the following $u$-substitution fail to find the correct value?

Let $u=\sin(x)$.
Then, $du=\cos(x) dx$ and $x=\arcsin(u)$.
For the bounds, $u=\sin(0)=0$ when $x=0$ and $u=\sin(\pi)=0$ when $x=\pi$.
In terms of $u$, it seems to follow that the integral $\int_0^0 u \arcsin(u) du$ is $0$; however, the correct value is $-\pi/4$.

What fact am I missing that causes the value to be incorrect when the $u$-substitution appears to be correct? I appreciate any help understanding.

Comment: Please use [MathJax](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference). To answer your question, when doing $u$-substitution you need to take into account the change in the sign of function.

Answer (score 4):

The problem is that $x = \arcsin(\sin(x))$ isn't true when $x > \pi/2$, so that it's not true that $x = \arcsin(u)$ for all $0 \leq x \leq \pi$.

In fact, for $0 \leq x \leq \pi$, we have
$$\arcsin(u) = \begin{cases}x, & \text{ if } 0 \leq x \leq \pi/2 \\ \pi - x, & \text{ if } \pi/2 \leq x \leq \pi\end{cases}$$

Answer (score 2):

It's not true that $u = \sin x$ implies that $x = \arcsin u$ everywhere on the interval $[0, \pi]$ of integration---after all, $\arcsin$ only takes values in the range $\left[-\frac\pi2,\frac\pi2\right]$. There are a few options for evaluating the integral. In increasing complexity:

(1) The standard choice, which in particular avoids the issue you identified, is applying integration by parts: Taking $v = x$, $dw = \sin x \cos x \,dx$ gives
$$\int_0^\pi x \sin x \cos x \,dx = \left.\frac{1}{2} x \sin^2 x\right\vert_0^\pi - \frac{1}{2} \int_0^\pi \sin^2 x \,dx = -\frac\pi4.$$

(2) It is true, on the other hand, that $y = \cos x$ implies that $x = \arccos y$ everywhere on the interval $[0, \pi]$, and applying that substitution gives
$$\int_0^\pi x \sin x \cos x \,dx = \int_{-1}^1 y \arccos y \,dy = -\frac{\pi}{2} + \int_{-1}^1 \frac{y^2 \,dy}{\sqrt{1 - y^2}} = -\frac{\pi}{2} + \int_{-\frac\pi2}^\frac\pi2 \sin^2 \theta \,d\theta = -\frac\pi4.$$

(3) Use the original substitution, $u = \sin x$. Split the integral of integration into two intervals, $\left[0, \frac\pi2\right]$ and $\left[\frac\pi2,\pi\right]$. On the first interval, $x = \arcsin u$, but on the second, $x = \pi - \arcsin u$. Then, the integral is
\begin{multline}\int_0^\frac\pi2 x \sin x \cos x \,dx + \int_\frac\pi2^\pi x \sin x \cos x \,dx \\ = \int_0^1 u \arcsin u \,du - \int_0^1 u (\pi - \arcsin u) du = \frac\pi8 - \frac{3\pi}{8} = -\frac\pi4.\end{multline}

Answer (score 0):

If you have $\int_a^b f(x) dx$ and you wish to evaluate it using $u=g(x)$, it must be the case that $\frac{f(x)}{g'(x)}$ is a function only of $u$ on $[a,b]$. In your case this does not occur; $x\sin(x)$ is not a function only of $\sin(x)$ on $[0,\pi]$, since for example the values differ at $x=\pi/4$ and $x=3\pi/4$.

One way to see this is to be a little bit more pedantic than usual, by thinking in terms of the chain rule explicitly. In this view, $u$ substitution is "identify $h,g$ such that $f(x)=h(g(x)) g'(x)$ and then integrate $h$".

In view of this observation, your particular strategy of substituting for $\sin(x)$ can be salvaged by splitting the integration at $\pi/2$, in which case you pick up $\int_0^1 u \arcsin(u) du + \int_1^0 u (\pi-\arcsin(u)) du$. Note how the representation of $x$ had to change from one integral to the other.